# Rendering Dust Template to nth child node

Tags: javascript, templates, dust.js

I am receiving a json object from the server that has tree menu data in it with nested elements and n amount of layers. I need this to be able to drill down to however many child elements their might be.

Is there a way to recursively loop through child elements of an object using Dust.js templates?

an example of this would be:

```
{#assignment}
     {#childAssignment}
         {#nChildAssignment}
             //etc, etc, etc into the dark pits of mordor
         {/nChildAssignment}
     {/childAssignemnt}
{/assignment}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a partial, and calling the partial recursively. So, if you have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "assignment": {
    "value": "foo",
    "assignment": {
      "value": "bar",
      "assignment": {
         ...
         "assignment": {
           "value": "last one"
         }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Then your template `recusive_assignment.dust` could look like this:

```
{#assignment}
  {value}
  {?.assignment}
    {>recursive_assignment.dust}
  {/.assignment}
{/assignment}
```